# Forest plot for meta-analysis of continous outcome displaying the mean ES with and without outliers

Tags: meta-analysis, metafor, forest-plot

I am conducting a meta-analysis and am trying to produce a forest plot displaying the mean weighted effect size with and without the outliers. I looked on so many websites and tried a lot of syntaxes, however, didn't really find anything about what I am looking for.

Assume there are 5 studies in the meta-analysis. Outlier analyses showed that Study 3 is an outlier leading to an overestimation of the mean weighted ES. Accordingly, I calculate a mean ES with (k = 5) and without the outlier (k = 3). I would like to display the studies sorted according to their ES and report both Mean ESs in the forest plot. I would appreciate any help and/or advice.

Study3 Study4 Study5

Mean ES (k = 5) Mean ES (k = 3)

**My code:**

```
    Ishtiaq <- data.frame(
  nexp = c(20, 30, 25, 18, 22),
  Pain_int_mean = c(-0.5, -0.8, -0.6, -1.2, -0.7),
  Pain_int_sd = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.25, 0.18, 0.22),
  ncon = c(18, 28, 23, 15, 20),
  Pain_con_mean = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.4, 0.6),
  Pain_con_sd = c(0.15, 0.25, 0.2, 0.18, 0.22),
  study_label = c("Study 1", "Study 2", "Study 3", "Study 4", "Study 5")
)
# calculate meta-analysis
Pain_meta <- metacont(nexp, Pain_int_mean, Pain_int_sd, ncon, Pain_con_mean, Pain_con_sd, studlab = study_label, data = Ishtiaq, sm = 'SMD', method.smd = "Hedges", method.tau = "REML")

# create forest plot
F1 = forest.meta(Pain_meta, sortvar = TE, studlab = TRUE, prediction = TRUE, 
                 test.overall.random = T, random = T, fixed = F    ,label.right = "Favours control", col.label.right = "black",
                 label.left = "Favours experimental", col.label.left = "black", col.square = "darkcyan", 
                 col.diamond = "darkblue", col.diamond.lines = "cyan4", col.predict = "red", print.tau2 = F,
                 mlab = "RE Model for All Studies (k = 5)")

#Remove studies with TE >5
Pain_meta_out_removed <-  abs(Pain_meta$TE) > 5

## Then, create the meta-analysis with outliers removed
Pain_meta_no_out = metacont(nexp, Pain_int_mean, Pain_int_sd, ncon, Pain_con_mean, Pain_con_sd, studlab = study_label, data = Ishtiaq[!Pain_meta_out_removed, ], sm = 'SMD', method.smd = "Hedges", method.tau = "REML", random = TRUE, fixed = FALSE)

#add the effect size to original plot

addpoly(Pain_meta_no_out, atransf=exp, mlab="RE Model with Outliers (k = 3)", cex=.75, vi = 'Pain_meta_no_out$TE', sei = 'Pain_meta_no_out$seTE')
```

Error in addpoly.default(Pain_meta_no_out, atransf = exp, mlab = "RE Model with Outliers (k = 3)",  :
Length of 'vi' (or 'sei') does not match length of 'x'

Comment: A reproducible example would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @JeremyMiles   I have updated the post with a reproducible code. Can you please suggest me how to do it now? thanks

Comment: You are not using the `metafor` package, but the `meta` package. In other words, functions `metacont()` and `forest.meta()` come from the `meta` package, while function `addpoly()` comes from the `metafor` package, but is totally incompatible with the functions from the `meta` package.

Comment: @Wolfgang Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I am using meta() function for a very long time and switching to metafor() is looking difficult for me. Is there any alternative than addpoly() to add the ES to the forest plot?
Is it possible to add manually ?
I will be grateful for your reply.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if this is possible with the `meta` package.

Answer (score 1):

It seems very questionable practice to exclude a study based on some automatic criterion flagging it as "an outlier". It may just be variation that just happens despite all studies addressing the same question in the same way, it may be that the "outlying" study actually measured what you really want while there's something wrong with the other studies, there might be genuine differences that are perfectly okay and all studies answer slightly different questions, or any kind of mixtures of the above.

Comment: My original dataset has outliers so I removed them. Just to make the code reproducible and simple I created a simple data(not real). I am not able to use addpoly to add the ES  to my forest plot containing ES of all studies.